# BizTalk 2013 CU2 - XMLReceive pipeline allowing malformed XML

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Scenario: I am upgrading a BizTalk 2006 app to BizTalk 2013. The messages it receives are infrequently malformed - the XML starts and then the text from some kind of Java exception encountered in the source is appended.

Instead of

```
<foo>
    <bar/>
    <baz/>
</foo>
```

I get

```
<foo>
    <bar/>OrderCreateMessageBean createLine() Exception =&gt;java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In BizTalk 2006, the malformed message would be caught in the default XMLReceive pipeline and using failed message routing, it could be dealt with. In BizTalk 2013, the default XMLReceive pipeline is permitting the malformed message through and then it fails in the downstream orchestration. The XMLReceive pipeline still seems to checking that the schema is deployed for message context promotion, but not checking for well-formed XML - I am NOT using validation in the pipeline, perhaps I now need to?

The other salient fact is that the BizTalk 2013 installation has CU2 applied, perhaps that introduced an issue.

So, I guess my questions are: did the behavior of the pipeline change between 2006 and 2013 and I missed it in the change documentation? Is this a known defect in either BizTalk 2013 or 2013 in combo with the CU2? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge, there have been several cases where XML validation between 2013 and earlier versions seem to behave slightly different.

Another case is this one: http://vincent.bloggingabout.net/2013/11/28/incorrect-validation-error-message-when-using-the-default-xmlreceive-pipeline-in-biztalk-2013/

Comment: Have you set the validate to true and specified a schema in the XML pipeline?  Even with previous versions BizTalk would not validate XML if you didn't set that. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nabeelp/archive/2008/05/14/biztalk-does-not-validate-my-message.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted MS Premier Support and gave them example code. Support forwarded the issue to the Product Group. The Product Group has acknowledged the defect. A fix should be available in the next CU per support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to set ValidateDocument to true in the XML disassembler pipeline component and specify the DocumentSpecName in there as well.

If you don't want to specify the schemas in the the XML disassembler, create a custom pipeline with both the XML disassembler and the XML validator with no need to change the default settings and use that on your receive location.

This is not something new, previous version of BizTalk also would not validate that the XML payload validated against the schema (see this blog [BizTalk Does Not Validate My Message?!?!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nabeelp/archive/2008/05/14/biztalk-does-not-validate-my-message.aspx)), but there is probably some other change in BizTalk that has now brought the issue to light.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. This is not about validating the XML against the schema. This is about well-formed xml. In 2006, a "bad" XML document - say without the closing tag, would suspend in the Receive Port, in 2013 it passes through the Receive Port. I am questioning this change in behavior. I do not want to validate the document contents against the schema, just ensure I have "legal" XML. I have found a workaround from another forum - set the RecoverableInterchangeProcess to true and it will exhibit the 2006 behavior - not ideal, but it works.